# CocoaPods Pod trunk delete not work

Tags: cocoapods

when I do:

```
 $ pod --version
```

> 0.39.0

but if I try:

```
$ pod trunk delete
```

> [!] Unknown command: `delete` Did you mean: register

Usage:

```
$ pod trunk COMMAND

  Interact with the CocoaPods API (e.g. publishing new specs)
```

Commands:

```
+ add-owner      Add an owner to a pod
+ info           Returns information about a Pod.
+ me             Display information about your sessions
+ push           Publish a podspec
+ register       Manage sessions
+ remove-owner   Remove an owner from a pod
```

Options:

```
--silent         Show nothing
--verbose        Show more debugging information
--no-ansi        Show output without ANSI codes
--help           Show help banner of specified command
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete isn't a command for trunk.
You have a list of valid commands in your post.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the CocoaPods documentation for `pod trunk delete` is referring to the command which has been added in the (currently unreleased) CocoaPods 1.0 beta. You can see in the `cocoapods-trunk` [changelog](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-trunk/blob/929d404c34c7b7e84e9442acb3a4380452cdd4cd/CHANGELOG.md#100beta1-2015-12-30) that this command has been added. Once that is released you'll be able to use it. In the meantime you *could* install the beta with

```
[sudo] gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Answer (score 0):

The command `pod trunk` is for the third-party libraries which are upload to cocoapods by yourselves.
And if you want to delete a version of your third-party library like ABCManager(v1.0.2),you can type this:`pod trunk delete ABCManager v1.0.2` and your library of version v1.0.2 will be deleted.